# adding two binary numbers(integer array)

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I have done this program to add two binary numbers of the same length stored in an integer array and store the sum in a new integer array. But due to some logical error, it does not show the desired output.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>

void main() {
    clrscr();
    int a[] = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
               1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};
    int b[] = {1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
               1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int temp[100];
    int carry = 0, p = 35;
    for(int i = 34; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(a[i] + b[i] + carry == 0) {
            temp[p] = 0;
            carry = 0;
            p--;
        }
        if((a[i] + b[i] + carry) == 1) {
            temp[p] = 1;
            carry = 0;
            p--;
        }
        if((a[i] + b[i] + carry) == 2) {
            temp[p] = 0;
            carry = 1;
            p--;
        }
        if((a[i] + b[i] + carry) > 2) {
            temp[p] = 1;
            carry = 1;
            p--;
        }
    }
    for(int pop = 0; pop < 36; pop++) cout << temp[pop];
    getch();
}
```

the expected output is:

> ```
> 110100101001100101101010110101011111
> ```

actual output is:

> ```
> 101100110011011101011011101011011111
> ```

Comment: With a more modern compiler you could simply use `std::bitset` and add the underlying values.

Comment: Shouldn't the `if` statements be `if`/`else if` statements. Also I'd recommend you should inspect your code with the debugger line by line to get a grasp what's going on.

Comment: You'll have to re-learn C++ if you start with `Turbo C++`. It's hopelessly outdated. `<iostream.h>` should be `<iostream>` and `void main()` should be `int main()`. Try to get your teacher to select one of the modern free compilers for your class instead.

Comment: @Ted I guess the user is from India, and they're forced to use it in school. Anything what you say is correct of course.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I changed it to else if but for no improvements. Yeah from India

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah well they won't change it. But even if i do this Dev-c++ by changing <iostream.h> to <iostream> followed by using namespace std and void main() to int main() it still yield the wrong output.

Comment: True, the logic of the program won't change with those changes, but it'll at least be closer to standard C++ :-) (the `conio.h` stuff would have to go away too though).

I tried to find an explaination as to why you have to use Turbo C++ (like import/export laws or something) but found: [Why is Turbo C++ still being used in Indian schools and colleges?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Turbo-C++-still-being-used-in-Indian-schools-and-colleges) so it still seems possible to get individual teachers/schools to step up.

Comment: @Adhiyaman So what were your observations when debugging your code line by line as I suggested? I believe you problem relates to `p` used as index for calculating the result. Shouldn't `i` be rather used there?

Comment: After you have added the `else`s, think about where the last carry is when you have added all the digits in the inputs.

Comment: Get in the habit of using small systematic test cases instead of huge arbitrary ones.  You can find all the bugs in a program like this using no more than two or three array elements.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, you'd need to implement your own addition operator for bitsets (easy enough, using `&`, `|` and `<<1`).  That's probably as educational as implementing bit-by-bit addition, so a good exercise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your code is you have a set of separate `if` statements which each modify `carry`, if `carry` is changed in such a way to alter the result of the subsequent `if` statements then multiple `if` statement bodies will be executed.

The simple fix is to change your last 3 `if`s to `else if`.

You also need to add the final carry bit to your output:

```
temp[0] = carry;
for(int pop = 0; pop < 36; pop++) cout << temp[pop];
```

However your code could be greatly simplified using a swtich statement. Simpler code is generally less buggy and easier to understand:

```
for(int i = 34; i >= 0; i--, p--) {
    switch(a[i] + b[i] + carry) {
    case 0:
        temp[p] = 0;
        carry = 0;
        break;
    case 1:
        temp[p] = 1;
        carry = 0;
        break;
    case 2:
        temp[p] = 0;
        carry = 1;
        break;
    case 3:
        temp[p] = 1;
        carry = 1;
        break;
    default:
        // should never be reached with inputs of 0 or 1
        throw std::invalid_argument("invalid input");
    }
}
```

This code could be simplified even further using bit manipulations to remove all branches and set the bits directly but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader [hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#/media/File:Full-adder_logic_diagram.svg).

Answer (score 3):

```
    if((a[i] + b[i] + carry) == 2) {
        temp[p] = 0;
        carry = 1;
        p--;
    }
    if((a[i] + b[i] + carry) > 2) {
        temp[p] = 1;
        carry = 1;
        p--;
    }
```

Go through this with `a[i] = 1, b[i] = 1, carry = 0`
This will trigger the first `if` here as it should, which then sets carry to 1.
Then the second `if` will find the configuration `a[i] = 1, b[i] = 1, carry = 1` which triggers it despite the original configuration not fitting, causing the bug.

For the future, please get to know how to use a debugger, or at least how to include some debugging console prints in the program. Set stop points or prints where there would be nodes in a corresponding diagram to see if the flow takes the right route.
With prints:

```
for(int i = 34; i >= 0; i--) {
    cout << "entered loop" << endl;
    if(a[i] + b[i] + carry == 0) {
        temp[p] = 0;
        carry = 0;
        p--;
        cout << "recognized case 1" << endl;
    }
    if((a[i] + b[i] + carry) == 1) {
        temp[p] = 1;
        carry = 0;
        p--;
        cout << "recognized case 2" << endl;
    }
    if((a[i] + b[i] + carry) == 2) {
        temp[p] = 0;
        carry = 1;
        p--;
        cout << "recognized case 3" << endl;
    }
    if((a[i] + b[i] + carry) > 2) {
        temp[p] = 1;
        carry = 1;
        p--;
        cout << "recognized case 4" << endl;
    }
}
```

(But using the debugger is better than prints.)